# Multiple select do not save for my custom field with custom widget

Tags: entities

I'm trying to save multiple values from multi select option form which I created in the custom widget with:

```
$element['labs'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $list,
  '#multiple' => 'multiple',
  '#title' => t('Labs'),
);
```

The biggest problem is the values won't save! As I know the delta should increment automatically if cardinality is set to more than 1.

1) I can't change cardinality or some other setting after activating the field in the **edit field form**

2) I can't see my custom field in the **field type list** to select from if I try to alter existing widgets:

```
'default_widget' => 'options_select',
'default_formatter' => 'status_field_options',
```

How could I extend standard list field type to populate the multiselect with my own generated data?

OR

How could I write my widget that Drupal let me save multiple values with different delta?

Answer (score 1):

The values won't save when you don't have any storage to write into.

Make sure your widget implements [`hook_field_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7) and provide necessary schema for a field structure in your `.install` file. E.g.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_schema().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_schema($field) {
  switch ($field['type']) {
    default:
      $columns = array(
        'value' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
      );
      break;
  }
  return array(
    'columns' => $columns,
    'indexes' => array(
      'value' => array('value'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then in [`hook_field_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7) make sure you've `FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT` for `multiple values` behavior, e.g.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'my_widget' => array(
      'label' => t('Default'),
      'field types' => array('select'),
      'behaviors' => array(
        'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

When implementing multiple field properties as part of one widget (such as address field), please check: [How to override default cardinality for the field widget?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/182135/1908)

For complete example, check existing modules under `field` core module or check [field_example module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/field_example?h=7.x-1.x) (part of [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)).